# Is it possible to output two sample levels from the same render?

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, interface, cache

I'm working on a sizable animation which may end up having around 512 samples to ideally handle hair follicles; maybe more. This is going to take time to do. Incidentally, I'm also on a soft deadline for it, and would love it if I could somehow do the following.

I would like to set the sample count to my ideal 512 for the final render, but have the same render, as of, say, 32 or 64 samples, output to a second image on disk. I would have a high-sample-count and a low-sample-count rendering. I would like to avoid doing the work of that first smaller-sample-count render twice; as there are over a thousand frames, and counting, on this animation and it's going to add up.

It occurs to me that Blender is in a specific state during the rendering process, which should be deterministic and enumerable, and it would wonderful if I could, say, render it in 32-samples first, and then cache that state somewhere on disk; then return to it when I'm ready for the all-out 512 sample render of the animation so it doesn't have to rework the first thirty two samples.

This animation is partially for a game, and if a set of textures/sprites/etc. could be modeled in low detail, they could be immediately inserted into, and "fitted" to, the code; then replaced with their higher-quality equivalents later on without any hassle.

I'm now wondering if this has already been done, and might be possible? I get that it would be dependent on an unchanged model, that's fine. It won't be a problem to do a handful of frames twice to correct an error, as long as I catch it at 32 samples.

Comment: If they understand the time constraint and limitations, would it be possible to give them an eevee render in the meantime?  It would be much quicker to iterate on any changes.  Edit: perhaps not with some of the features you're using, idk

Comment: This feature which will be available in one of the next versions  might help https://developer.blender.org/rBc63e735f6b601e662fbb1ed5d7a71293552d6720

Comment: @Gorgious That is a juicy-looking feature which I will definitely use down the line! Unfortunately it'll happen well after my deadline. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelMacha Well I believe it is already available in the latest 3.1 alpha version which you can download. Although wouldn't recommend using on full production project, creating a standalone file just for rendering can't really hurt the rest of the workflow. Food for thought :) https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/

Comment: @Gorgious, an interesting notion, I'm hoping to wait for 3.1 before I depend on it for a project in an alpha state, though. If I slip up and lose access to a file, it's of course a big deal.

Comment: @Allen Simpson I actually am generally using Eevee for initial geometry checks, it's wonderful for that. You're right, though, some features only work on a ray tracer like Cycles; if I've got some kind of material error Eevee may not catch it. If it's a firefly problem, it definitely won't! But thank you!